# Is there any synchronization problem in this program

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, language-lawyer

Consider the following program.
(i) What would be the output in Line A and Line B? Justify your answer.
(ii) Do you think there is synchronization problem in updating the variable value?
Justify your answer.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int value = 100;
void *thread_prog(void *param);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread_prog, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
    value = value + 100;
    printf("Parent value = %d\n", value); //Line A
}
void *thread_prog(void *param)
{
    value = value + 100;
    printf("Child value = %d\n", value); // Line B
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

The output will be Line A is 300 and Line B is 200
I don't think there is a synchronization problem because of the  `pthread_join(tid, NULL);`

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted. It's actually asking a subtle but very important question in addition to the ordering problem: what guarantees does C provide that the result of `value = value + 100;` in the child thread are ***visible*** to the main thread after the child thread exits.  Synchronization in mulithreaded programs isn't only about before/after, it's also about what's visible.

Comment: And never mind how [C programs are specified to execute](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.3).  Can a compiler assume that `value` retains its initialized value of 100 and just replace `printf("Parent value = %d\n", value);` with `printf("Parent value = %d\n", 200);` in the main thread?  I honestly don't know offhand.

Comment: [tag:language-lawyer] "*For questions about the intricacies of formal or authoritative specifications of programming languages and environments*" So, here we need to know which "formal or authoritative specifications" you are referring to. The ISO C specification? POSIX? Or both?

Comment: @curiousguy I'm a bit slow responding here, but I think it's safe to assume most current C standard applies.  I used the final C11 draft for quotes as it's effectively identical to the actual C11 standard and there's marked-up HTML copy available online, and it's close enough to C17/18.,

Comment: @AndrewHenle The C std doesn't cover `pthread_create` and co.

Comment: @curiousguy Not the POSIX implementation, but [it does cover threading](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.26).  And of course the abstract machine semantics.  Both of which apply to answer the portions of this question that I've passed on - because I know there are more than few contributors here that are much more qualified than I am to address those issues.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I don't agree w/ your claim the C spec covers threads. I don't see how anything is defined re: threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the posted code, the control flow is obvious, so there are no issues with before-after ordering relationships.  But proper synchronization of multithreaded code requires more than just establishing proper before-after relationships.

There are two additional aspects that need to be addressed to ensure this code has no synchronization issues.

- Are the changes made in the child thread visible in the main thread?
- Do [the semantics of the C abstract machine](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.3) preclude a C compiler from assuming that the contents of the variable `value` does not change while the main thread is running?

This answer only addresses the first concern.

It's not sufficient to merely establish a guaranteed before-after relationship in multithreaded code to ensure a change to a variable is seen in its entirety by another thread.  The [Wikipedia entry on "memory barrier" provides a good explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier):

> A memory barrier, also known as a membar, memory fence or fence instruction, is a type of barrier instruction that causes a central processing unit (CPU) or compiler to enforce an ordering constraint on memory operations issued before and after the barrier instruction. This typically means that operations issued prior to the barrier are guaranteed to be performed before operations issued after the barrier.
>
> Memory barriers are necessary because most modern CPUs employ performance optimizations that can result in out-of-order execution. This reordering of memory operations (loads and stores) normally goes unnoticed within a single thread of execution, but can cause unpredictable behaviour in concurrent programs and device drivers unless carefully controlled. The exact nature of an ordering constraint is hardware dependent and defined by the architecture's memory ordering model. Some architectures provide multiple barriers for enforcing different ordering constraints.

In other words, a change made to a variable running on, for example, CPU 1 may not be "seen" by another thread running on, say, CPU 7 even though the code runs on CPU 7 after the code that changed the variable ran on CPU 1.

There needs to be some sort of platform-specific implementation of a guarantee that such changes are propagated through the actual hardware and visible.

And POSIX's threading model specifies those exact guarantees.

Per [POSIX **4.12 Memory Synchronization**](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_12) (bolding mine):

> Applications shall ensure that access to any memory location by more than one thread of control (threads or processes) is restricted such that no thread of control can read or modify a memory location while another thread of control may be modifying it. Such access is restricted using functions that synchronize thread execution and also synchronize memory with respect to other threads. **The following functions synchronize memory with respect to other threads**:
>
> ```
>  .
>  .
>  .
> pthread_create()
> pthread_join()
>  .
>  .
>  .
> ```

The use of `pthread_create()` and `pthread_join()` not only establishes the before-after ordering relationship needed for proper synchronization, but per the POSIX standard they also establish the visibility requirements.

So yes, the posted code is properly synchronized in guaranteed before-after ordering and also visbility aspects.

Note, though, this answer does not address the question of whether or not the posted code is properly synchronized per the semantics of the C abstract machine.  I'll defer to experts with better understanding of the C standard and the interpretation of its abstract machine in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

You assume correctly that there is no synchronization problem, pthread_join() suspends the calling thread until the target thread terminates.  If the target thread already has terminated, it returns immediately.  In any case, the target case is executed and terminated before line A is output.

Comment: So it means that there is no synchronization problem?